# How to show 4000 characters in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have bind my dataset to crystal report, it has one of the column with 4000 characters but crystal report is unable to show it
How to display 4000 characters in Crystal report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your field is text so do `right click` -> `Format Text` and on tab `Common` click `can grow` option (red on picture). Then that field adjust to the size of content.
[image]

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**

If your did this and your field still don't work then you should split that field into several other fields. For instance if my field contains 4000 characters and i know that i can't show 4000 characters on 1 page then i split that field into half and on 1 page i can show 2000 characters (first part of field) and on second page other 2000 characters (second part of field).

To do that (split field into 2 parts):

1. make 2 new formula fields `part1` and `part2`
2. write formulas for each part (it's cutting string into n parts)

Part 1 formula

```
MID({field}, 1,length({field})/2)
```

Part2 formula

```
MID({field}, length({field})/2, length({field}))
```

After that if you still don't succeed then to for n parts until you succeed (3 or more). Maybe there is better solution but i thinked only about that one.

Hope it helps you.

**EDIT 2 :**

If you see whole text in part 1 then ignore part 2. To make that each part is in separated page, then add additional detail section and then you have:

1. detail section a - put part1 here
2. detail section b - put part2 here

Right click on detail section -> Section Expert and put checkbox like on picuture below. After that you should have each part on separated pages.

[image]

Comment: if i tick 'can grow', it will make my report empty, I think I overlaps the design. what is the alternative ?

Comment: @koolprasad2003 My answer is updated. Hope it solves your problem now.

Comment: Thanks up KuKeC, now I can see my whole text in part 1 but there is no second page displayed in crystal report viewer ? what could be the error ?

Comment: @koolprasad2003 My answer is updated once again. Hope it solves your problem now